# noob project to learn Spring/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to get my feet wet with Spring/Hibernate. But I think I move along faster and am more motivated if I am working with code rather than just reading a book chapter by chapter.

Does anyone have any good ideas for a home project to work on to learn these technologies? Any exercises that you might have worked on and thought useful?

Or perhaps you know of a book/tutorial that is based on a single project and walks you through it?

Answer (score 9):

[AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home) is a Spring & Hibernate app designed to be used as skeleton for new projects. Install it, run maven, you have a working project you can study, inspect, debug, modify or add to as you wish. I've worked on a couple of enterprise apps that started as AppFuse.

Comment: No idea about AppFuse until your post! +1 for this!

Comment: Not sure but when I try to access it shows not found.

Answer (score 4):

I hope you would have some existing applications, previously done with different tech and framework. The best is to implement those with Hibernate and Spring.

Comment: +1 I found this a good approach when learning as you can concentrate on the tech and not get bogged down in the details of what the app should do

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Appfuse, too, as *tpdi* does. A couple of details:

- Use "Spring MVC Basic" project;
- start with the Quickstart, and stick to it;
- when you're confident enough, go deeper with each technology / layer.

You will find yourself digging in documentation, but with an already working project. Appfuse ha very few "special" classes & utilities, once you master it you can anytime start from scratch... but it's easier with it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need something simple but not trivial and complex but not complicated.

Try making a timetabling system or calendar